# ListView in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

Am developing a game application in android. In my application I'm having levels and added levels as a list view. 
Now I need to lock the levels after achieving level goal. i dont know how to do. How to lock `listview` in android. By using the following I'm populating the list and passing.

```
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
        // mainListView.setSelection(0);
        String[] levels = new String[] { "Level-1", "Level-2", "Level-3",
                "Level-4", "Level-5", "Level-6" };
        ArrayList<String> levelList = new ArrayList<String>();
        levelList.addAll(Arrays.asList(levels));

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple, levelList);

        mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
        getlevelFromDb();
        mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                    int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                String level = (String) (mainListView
                        .getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                Intent intent = new Intent(LevelsActivity.this,
                        QuestionActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("level", level);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: What do you mean "lock the levels"?

Comment: Game application have 5 levels means. Player need to pass the level 1 goal to play level 2. So need to lock or hide other levels(list items)

Comment: Use SharedPreferences for store the level count in your application. It will remain until your application removed.

Answer (score 2):

In this case I would have essentially a boolean array (of some sort, there are many ways of accomplishing those types of values) that parallels the levels array.  To lock them from being actioned on, you could put a check against this boolean array within the action itself (the onItemClick).  In this way you could only action off when you see a true, and do nothing, or put up a little view that says they havent made it that far or something if the array states false.

When they pass the level, you can then simply apply a true value to the next level, and the action for the item in the listview should automatically pick up.

If you wanted to gray out the levels that are not yet unlocked, then you would have to implement a custom ArrayAdapter for the ListView!!!

Comment: Keep in mind that just arrays will go away as soon as you close the App and maybe sooner, you need to store them somewhere every time a level is unlocked.

Comment: @mbwasi - Good point, something I would think inherent may not be to another :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Strings as your level id's, then you're going to have to add the Strings to your array as new levels are unlocked.

Alternatively you could use a custom Level-class with a boolean flag 'unlocked' along with a custom ListAdapter to only show levels, that are unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Jarkko has the best solution, but if you want to keep is simple you need to store the unlocked levels somewhere (Shared preferences would work) then before launching the level activity you need to check if the level is unlocked. So

```
if (isLevelUnlocked(level)){
    startActivity(intent);
}else{
    //Level is not unlocked yet, display a msg to the user.
}
```